# How should a node.js stack for a high demand application be setup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mean-stack

I'm currently working on a Node.js stack application used by over 25000 people, we're using Sails.js framework in particular and we got MongoDB 
Application is running at a EC2 instance with 30GB of RAM, databse is running on a Mongolab AWS based cluster in same zone the EC2 is. We even got an Elastic Cache Redis instance with 1.5GB for storage.

So the main and huge problem we're facing is **LATENCY**. When we reach a peak of concurrent users requesting application we're getting multiple timeouts and sails application reaching over 7.5GB of RAM, HTTP requests to API take longer than 15 seconds (which is unacceptable) and when even get 502 and 504 responses sent by nginx.

I can notice Mongo write operations as our main latency issue, however even GET requests take long when a demand peak is present. I can't access production servers, I only got a keymetrics monitoring tool by pm2 (which is actually great) and New Relic alerts.

So, I'd like to know some roadmap to cope these issues, maybe more detailed information should be offered, so far I can say application seems stable when not much users are present.

What are main factors and setup to consider?

So far I know *what I should do*, but I'm not sure about details or the *hows*.

IMHO:

1. Cache as much as possible.
2. Delay MongoDB write operations.
3. Separate Mongo databases with higher write demand.
4. Virtualize?
5. Tune up node setups.

On optimising code, I've posted another stackoverflow question with one example of [code patterns I'm following](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98815/).

**What are your advise and opinion for production applications?**

Comment: See [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-testing-mongodb-30-part-1-throughput-improvements-measured-ycsb) if you're using MongoDB 2.x

Comment: What about blocking, synchronous, or long running operation? Clustering per CPU-cores?

Comment: @stdob-- can you extend your comment in an answer, some longer comments and examples would be appreciated

Comment: It sound like a mongodb configuration issue to me. Where you haven't optimized your disk configuration or indexes. For proper disk configuration check this out: http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/ebs-mongo-dbwebinarfinal-nn

Comment: How do you run your application ? 
Did it use only one node.js instance (only one process). Or you are using some cluster system ? 
How many cores do you have on your EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically most of main points are already present in answers.  I'll just summarise them.

To optimize your application you could do several main things.

1. Try to move form `node.js` to `io.js` it still have a bit better performance and latest cutting edge updated. (But read carefully about experimental features). Or at least from `node.js` `v10` to `v12`. There was lot of performance optimisations.
2. Avoid using synchronous functions that uses I/O operations or operating with big amount of data.
3. Switch from one node process to [clustering](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) system.
4. Check your application to memory leaks. I'm using [memwatch-next](https://github.com/marcominetti/node-memwatch) for `node.js v12` and [memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) for `node.js v10`
5. Try to avoid saving data to global variables
6. Use caching. For data that should be accessible globally you could use `Redis` or `Memcached` is also a great store.
7. Avoid of using `async` with `Promises`. Both libs are doing same things. So no need to use both of them. (I saw that in your code example).
8. Combine `async.waterfall` with `async.parallel` methods where it could be done.
   For example if you need to fetch some data from mongo that is related only to user, you could fetch user and then in parallel fetch all other data you need.
9. If you are using `sails.js` make sure that it's in `production` mode. (I assume you already did this)
10. Disable all hooks that you don't need. In most cases `grunt` hook is useless.And if you don't need `Socket.io` in your application - disable it using `.sailsrc` file. Something like:

    {
      "generators": {
        "modules": {}
      },
      "hooks": {
        "grunt": false,
        "sockets": false
      }
    }

Another hooks that could be disabled are: `i18n`, `csrf`, `cors`. BUT only if you don't use them in your system.

11. Disable useless globalisation. In `config/globals.js`. I assume `_`, `async`, `services` could be disabled by default. Just because `Sails.js` uses old version of `lodash` and `async` libraries and new versions has much better performance.
12. Manually install `lodash` and `async` into `Sails.js` project and use new versions. (look point 11)
13. Some "write to mongo" operations could be made after returning result to user. For example: you can call `res.view()` method that will send response to user before `Model.save()` BUT code will continue running with all variables, so you could save data to mongo DB. So user wouldn't see delay during write operation.
14. You could use queues like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) to perform operations that require lot of resources. For example: If you need to store big data collection you could send it to `RabbitMQ` and return response to user. Then handle this message in "background" process ad store data. It will also can help you with scaling your application.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, ensure that you are not using synchronous I/O.  If you can run on `io.js`, there is `--trace-sync-io` flag (`iojs --trace-sync-io server.js`) that will warn you if you use synchronous code with the following console warning: `WARNING: Detected use of sync API`.

Secondly, find out why your RAM usage goes so high.  If it's because of lots of data loaded into memory (XML parsing, large amount of data returned from MongoDB, etc), you should consider using `streams`.  V8 garbage collection (Google's JavaScript VM used in `Node.js` / `io.js`) may cause slowdown if your memory usage goes very high.  More here: [Node.js Performance Tip of the Week: Managing Garbage Collection](http://Node.js%20Performance%20Tip%20of%20the%20Week:%20Managing%20Garbage%20Collection) and [Node.js Performance Tip of the Week: Heap Profiling](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-heap-profiling-tip/)

Thirdly, experiment with [Node.js clustering](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-scaling-proxies-clusters/) and [MongoDB sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/).

Lastly, check if you using or can switch to `MongoDB` 3.x.  We've observed some significant  performance gains just by upgrading from 2.x to 3.x.

Comment: Is it only running that and it will debug?

Answer (score 2):

For Mongodb you can use [mongtop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) to see which databases are contested, 2.2+ uses per database locks, if database has write heavy workload reads will be affected as mongodb is using [writer greedy locks](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use)

And for node.js you could check if there are any sort of event loop delays which could explain API request delays

```
(function getEventLoopDelay() {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(Math.max(Date.now() - startTime - 1000, 0));
        getEventLoopDelay();
    }, 100);
})();
```

Comment: What should I look or not to look for that code snippet?

Comment: anything above 10-20ms should indicate that event loop gets saturated and it requests get queued before execution